# Alter Views arguments from URL

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'd like to alter Views arguments which is currently Term name. Is there any way to use term name slug instead of complete Term name and use this slug as views argument? If not what hook should I use to convert these parameters from URL (as taxonomy term slug) to full name Taxonomy term which can be used as views argument. I tried to use hook_views_query_alter and hook_views_pre_view, but it's too late for any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a build in function in drupal views. When you add a contextual filter there would a section called more. You can put the case to lower case and check "Transform spaces to dashes in URL"

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for but I found another problem [link](http://drupal.org/node/368414). However, your solution is fully enough to me.